# How to synchronize next generated value between multiple clients?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a web service in which I have a method that generates an incremental number. Then the last created is saved in a database. So next time the client requests a new number, it uses the last saved and increments it with one.

The numbers look like that:

```
PREFIX-12345
PREFIX-12346
PREFIX-12347
```

This works well, but now there is the concurrency problem, if two or more clients call the method at the same time, then it's possible that they might get the same numbers.

I am thinking that I can create a stored procedure that can get the number, generate the next and then lock it somehow, so if there's another request at the same time, it will increment with two.

Now my problem is that I don't know how to lock the next number, so that anybody trying to get a number at the same time, can get a different one?

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention, the table structure is like that:

```
ID | LastSavedNumber
1  |     12345
2  |     12346
3  |     12347
4  |     12348
```

Comment: Push your identity field generation to your database layer. By implementing locking, you are preventing multiple requests from being serviced and your application will become unscalable.

Comment: You have to exclusively lock place where current value is stored. Unless you do so, anyone can obtain _current value_ and thereafter generate next one.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Can you please elaborate a little more on the push of the identity field generation to the database layer?

Comment: If you wanna keep the generation in DB, my advice is replace the select last + 1 with a table with an identity column and every time you need you need the next number just insert a new line and return the automatically generated number. The identity columns in Sql Server already handle concurrency

Comment: You could, for instance, create a [Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx) and pull next value from that.

Comment: I would recommend not using a prefix for anything with data. If it is a static prefix it is just wasted effort. If the prefix changes for different rows then you are violating 1NF by storing multiple piece of data in a single tuple.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Seems like the Sequence is not available in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You could create your own table of available identifiers and remove from it as you consume them; within a transaction of course. Or just just an integer identity column in your table - you can always apply a transformation to it in your business layer.